# How to add user in mongodb 2.2?

Tags: mongodb

Please I want to know how to add user in mongodb 2.2 I know createuser in mongodb 2.6 But can I add user in Mongodb 2.2?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.2/reference/method/db.addUser/
 Please refer this document it has an db.addUser() method for adding datas

Answer (score 0):

//If you want to restrict a user to read only then set
 3rd paramenter to true by default it is set to false

db.addUser("userName" , "Password" , true )